# Triggering location updates at certain time for certain period

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In my iOS app I wish to trigger location updates for a certain duration for certain period of time.
For instance I wish to start updating location to server at 5:00 pm tomorrow until 7:00 pm same day.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I am not looking for code but some flow/algorithm to achieve this.

Comment: I think your next challenge will be that the app will be in suspended state at 5pm and no code will be executed to start the location updates. To keep the app alive in background, you will have to pick a strategy, one of which is to keep the location updates alive at all times.

Comment: I guess voip is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I hope you know how to set up basic CoreLocation environment such as adding locationUsageDescription to info.plist and enabling background mode. So i wont explain those, here is my code. You can add this code to AppDelegate or any ViewController you wish to add. In my case i have added to AppDelegate-

```
- (void)initializeLocationManager {

    /* These are dummy _startTime and _endTime, you can set up the required dateTime as per your requirement
        _startTime is set to current dateTime + 60 seconds
        _endTime is set to _start time + 60 seconds
    */
    _startTime = [NSDate date];
    // secondsToAdd - 60 seconds
    NSTimeInterval secondsToAdd = 60;
    _startTime = [_startTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsToAdd];
    _endTime = [_startTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsToAdd];

    NSLog(@"Start time = %@", _startTime);
    NSLog(@"endtime = %@", _endTime);

    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    // You can use requestWhenInUseAuthorization/ requestAlwaysAuthorization depending on your requirement
    if([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        [self initializeLocationManager];
        return YES;
    }
```

And implement the CLLocationManagerDelegate as

```
#pragma mark CLLocationManager Delegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't update location, Location services are not enabled");
    }

    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {

        NSLog(@"Couldn't update location, Location services not authorized.");

    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // Compare _startTime with the current dateTime
    // If _startTime is less than current dateTime, then you can start sending updates to your server

    switch ([_startTime compare:[NSDate date]]) {
        case NSOrderedAscending:

            // You can add condition to restrict the frequency of updating location
            // Like here, I have added condition to send updates every 60 seconds

            //  lastLocationUpdatedTime should be initialize before calling [self initializeLocationManager];
            //  lastLocationUpdatedTime = [NSDate date];

            // if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:lastLocationUpdatedTime] > (1*60)) {
            //   lastLocationUpdatedTime = [NSDate date];
            //   NSLog(@"send location update to server");
            //   }
            NSLog(@"send location update to server");

            if ([_endTime compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                NSLog(@"end updates");
            //  Stop updating location
                [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            }
            break;
        case NSOrderedSame:
            // If equals you can add your logic here...
            break;
        case NSOrderedDescending:
            // If startime is greater than time [NSDate date]
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This however wont work if the app is in the suspended mode. So we have two things here:
1. Wake up app from the suspended mode
2. Run it for a while before stoppingLocaitonUpdate (making sure it does not get suspended after 10 mins )

Comment: If the app is in suspended mode and if there is no significant change in location. Then this wont work, but if there's a significant change in location, regardless of the suspension mode the app will wake up for some seconds( like 10 seconds). Other than this, i don't see any option unless you are dealing with voip apps